# Making background transparent in JPEG Image by converting to PNG

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing

I'm trying to make the background transparent in the following image. See images below.

[Before conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mx5c.jpg)

[Required Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1XE1.png)

Using the Opencv and matplotlib, I was able to achieve this.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#== Parameters =======================================================================
BLUR = 21
CANNY_THRESH_1 = 10
CANNY_THRESH_2 = 200
MASK_DILATE_ITER = 10
MASK_ERODE_ITER = 10
MASK_COLOR = (0.0,0.0,1.0) # In BGR format


#== Processing =======================================================================

#-- Read image -----------------------------------------------------------------------
img = cv2.imread('/home/hasher/Documents/30302649.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#-- Edge detection -------------------------------------------------------------------
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, CANNY_THRESH_1, CANNY_THRESH_2)
edges = cv2.dilate(edges, None)
edges = cv2.erode(edges, None)

#-- Find contours in edges, sort by area ---------------------------------------------
contour_info = []
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for c in contours:
    contour_info.append((
        c,
        cv2.isContourConvex(c),
        cv2.contourArea(c),
    ))
contour_info = sorted(contour_info, key=lambda c: c[2], reverse=True)
max_contour = contour_info[0]

#-- Create empty mask, draw filled polygon on it corresponding to largest contour ----
# Mask is black, polygon is white
mask = np.zeros(edges.shape)
cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, max_contour[0], (255))



#-- Smooth mask, then blur it --------------------------------------------------------
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=MASK_DILATE_ITER)
mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=MASK_ERODE_ITER)
mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (BLUR, BLUR), 0)

mask_stack = np.dstack([mask]*3)    # Create 3-channel alpha mask

#-- Blend masked img into MASK_COLOR background --------------------------------------
mask_stack  = mask_stack.astype('float32') / 255.0          # Use float matrices, 
img         = img.astype('float32') / 255.0                 #  for easy blending

masked = (mask_stack * img) + ((1-mask_stack) * MASK_COLOR) # Blend
masked = (masked * 255).astype('uint8')                     # Convert back to 8-bit 

# plt.imsave('/home/hasher/Documents/girl_blue.png', masked)
# split image into channels
c_red, c_green, c_blue = cv2.split(img)

# merge with mask got on one of a previous steps
img_a = cv2.merge((c_blue, c_green, c_red, mask.astype('float32') / 255.0))

# show on screen (optional in jupiter)
#%matplotlib inline
plt.imshow(img_a)
plt.show()

# save to disk
# cv2.imwrite('/home/hasher/Documents/girl_1.png', img_a*255)

# or the same using plt
plt.imsave('/home/hasher/Documents/transparent.png', img_a)

# cv2.imshow('img', masked)  # Displays red, saves blue

cv2.waitKey()
```

I was able to convert image to [After conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKHtf.png) (See image).
But there are minor issues in code. There is some extra details in borders of converted image. I'm not able to figure out. Any help is appreciated.

Samples before conversion. [sample-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NayT2.jpg) [sample-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmXge.jpg) [sample-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhRZT.jpg) 
 [sample-4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2A1tk.jpg)

Comment: Why is the `MASK_COLOR` set to `1` only on the red channel. Set all the channels to 1.0 and test it out. And also note that the split and merge function uses the order blue,green,red format as the default one. In your code, c_red actually has blue color pixels and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Task: Convert `JPEGs with specific color background` into  `transparent PNGs`.
>
> (1) JPEGs

[image]

> (2) For these jpegs, convert them into HSV and split channels. Then We can seperate the target in the V channel because the background is most different with other channels.

[image]

> (3) Threshold the V channel and do morph-op, then we can get a alpha mask and the png.

[image]

[image]

---

> The code:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np 

fname = "alpha.jpg"
img = cv2.imread(fname)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

v = hsv[:,:,2]
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(v, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU|cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
threshed[-1] = 255

cnts = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2]

mask = np.zeros_like(threshed)
cv2.drawContours(mask, cnts, -1, (255, 0, 0), -1, cv2.LINE_AA)
mask = cv2.erode(mask, np.ones((3,3), np.int32), iterations=1)

png = np.dstack((img, mask))
cv2.imwrite("alpha.png", png)
```

Comment: In my case, all my origin images have the background I want to make backgrounds transparent. I want to do the reverse.

Comment: Any suggestions or ideas for doing the reverse?

Comment: If the image is in lossless  format and the background color is constant, then we can try `inRange` to find the color mask. But as we all know, the `JPEG` is `lossy compression` format. So It is not easy to recovery the `edges info` in the image. Maybe it will be easy to handle if the the source is in `PNG` format.

Comment: After the initial conversion, I'm saving images in png format. Can I do further processing on that to achieve the required output?

Comment: Could you please provide some PNG samples?

Comment: Added a few png samples in the question. @Silencer

Comment: Do you have the origin images (before conversions) in `PNG` format, or you only have the `JPEG`sources ?

Comment: I only have JPEG sources.

Comment: OK, but you samples' background is black, while the `before conversion`'s is colorful. I want some like the before conversion (not the converted).

Comment: Added before conversion samples.

Comment: Can share the code for inverse or at least can you tell how you did it?

Comment: As far as I can see, you found the rgb values of Background colour and removed pixels with those values from the whole image. Is that right ?

Comment: First convert to HSV, then I find all the cartoons have black borders. Then threshold the V channels and do morph-op and find by contour.

Comment: Can you please share the code? I tried but not able to get as perfect as yours. It'd be of great help if you can share code. Thank you.

Comment: Thank You. It's perfect.

Comment: Hi @Kinght金 wanted to do same, tried above code but gives different result.
i have posted question, need your input
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66206209/transparent-background-in-jpeg-image-by-converting-to-png-in-python