# How to get transparent background from JPEG Image by converting to PNG?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library

I want to make the background of an image (jpg/jpeg) transparent white.

Below is my code which transfers green background to white (correctly identify edge of person):
[Input image](https://i.imgur.com/rmQRJIS) to [Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTYrt.jpg)

```py
def change_bg(img, bg=(255, 255, 255)):
    # convert to hsv
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # threshold using inRange
    range1 = (20, 80, 80)
    range2 = (90, 255, 255)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, range1, range2)
    mask = 255 - mask

    # apply morphology opening to mask
    kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel)
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

    # antialias mask
    mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (0, 0), sigmaX=3, sigmaY=3, borderType=cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    mask = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(mask, in_range=(127.5, 255), out_range=(0, 255))

    result = img.copy()
    result[mask == 0] = bg
    return result
```

With below code, I convert the jpeg image to png, but I see some white pixels which are not transparent: [Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VAL3.png)

```py
def white_to_transe(image):
    """
    @input: PIL image
    @return:
    """
    image = image.convert('RGBA')
    # Transparency
    newImage = []
    for item in image.getdata():
        if item[:3] == (255, 255, 255):
            newImage.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
        else:
            newImage.append(item)

    image.putdata(newImage)
    print(image.mode, image.size)
    return newImage
```

So, how to get clean white transparent background?

After updating `white_to_transe` with below, it works, but it will impact on white pixels, say the white shirt for example:

```py
    for item in image.getdata():
        if item[0] > 240 and item[1] > 240 and item[2] > 240:
            newImage.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
```

Is it possible, that instead of putting white (all 255), we add transparent in `change_bg` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach might be somehow unfortunate. When antialiasing your mask, you get values in the range `0 ... 255`, but you only set `result[mask == 0] = bg` (white). You don't take into account all the other pixels, which (gradually) also belong the original mask. So, I would re-arrange your code, and simply use the final mask as the alpha channel. I did that also using OpenCV; using the additional Pillow loop feels somehow cumbersome from my point of view.

That'd be a modified excerpt from your code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure

img = cv2.imread('rmQRJIS.jpg')
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower = (40, 80, 80)
upper = (90, 255, 255)
mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower, upper)
mask = 255 - mask

kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# Use initial, binary mask to set background to white
result = img.copy()
result[mask == 0] = (255, 255, 255)

# Save image just for intermediate output
cv2.imwrite('output_no_trans.png', result)

# Use antialiased mask as final alpha channel for transparency
mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (0, 0), sigmaX=3, sigmaY=3, borderType=cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
mask = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(mask, in_range=(127.5, 255), out_range=(0, 255))
result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
result[:, :, 3] = mask

# Save final image
cv2.imwrite('output.png', result)
```

As an intermediate output, I saved the image after setting the background to white:

[image: Intermediate output]

The final output including the alpha channel looks like this:

[image: Final output]

To be honest, the difference can be hardly seen here, since I had to downscale the output images before uploading to maintain `PNG` compatibility. Please, have a look at the fullsized images yourself, if the result is in your favor!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
NumPy:         1.20.1
OpenCV:        4.5.1
scikit-image:  0.18.1
----------------------------------------
```